# FileUpload in Chrome giving some fake path value

Tags: google-chrome, httpwebrequest

I am trying to upload a file in Chrome then it is giving some fakepath value.for eg. It is giving file name like "C:\fakepath\Hi.txt" .Could you please explain me why it is coming?
In other browsers it is working fine.

Comment: How does this question relate to Java?

Comment: Why do you care for exact path anyway on server?

Comment: @PeterLawrey done the required changes.

Comment: @Akashkava I want to remove it to make my code error free and I want to know why the path coming like this.

Comment: You are supposed to just ignore the path and use file name.

Comment: @AkashKava thanks for useful comment.Now doing same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome shows it for security purpose.

Also check this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68471/the-image-uploader-shows-fakepath-as-path-when-using-chrome) on meta stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Its for security purposes that you can't get actual physical path of the uploaded file.

```
 document.getElementById("yourFileInput").files[0].fileName;
```

this will get you the filename from uploaded path.